# Saisir l'occasion et profiter de l'occasion

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Est-ce qu’il y a des différences entre « Saisir l’occasion » ou « Profiter de l’occasion » ? Je n’arrive pas à comprendre quand utiliser l’une ou l’autre, car pour moi elles ont la même signification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans le premier cas, on insiste sur la rapidité de l'action, cette occasion n'était peut-être accessible que durant une période très limitée alors que dans le deuxième cas, on insiste sur l'aspect positif de l'action.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux expressions signifient exactement la même chose.

Cependant, "saisir" renvoie l'idée d'une action volontaire, tandis que "profiter" semble plus passif, voire opportuniste.

J'illustre mon propos par une citation :

> La chance ne sourit qu'aux esprits bien préparés.
>
> **Louis Pasteur**

Comment: +1 L'opposition action volontaire/action passive me semble la plus à même de distinguer ces deux expressions.

Answer (score 1):

*Saisir l'occasion* (ou encore plus *sauter sur l'occasion*) signifie d'une situation rare se présente et qu'il faut réagir vite pour pouvoir en profiter.

> On m'a proposé un boulot à 250000 €/an ; **j'ai sauté sur l'occasion** !

*Profiter de l'occasion* c'est plutôt tirer le meilleur parti d'une situation plus ou moins négative. En anglais, on pourrait dire *to make the best out of a situation*.

> Je devais attendre 3h à l'aéroport. **J'ai profité de l'occasion pour** aller chez le coiffeur.

Plus couramment, on dira *en profiter pour* faire quelque chose, "en" désignant la situation.

> Je devais attendre 3h à l'aéroport et **j'en ai profité pour** aller chez le coiffeur.